# Warning Unresponsive script in angular.js, line 3627

Tags: angularjs, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am trying to setup Django Rest Auth using an Angular JS front end so I am using this [application](https://github.com/Tivix/angular-django-registration-auth) as my base.

I followed the instructions on the page to set things up. However, when I go my localhost, the page stops working, the browser stops working and I get a report saying this:

> A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding.
>   You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let
>   the script continue.
>
> Script:
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/angular-1.5.0/angular.min.js:192

Note I have all my angular files on my static folder and the terminal says that it is able to find all angular and template files properly (HTML status code 200)

I have also installed all the dependencies required by the sample app like so:

```
<!-- AngularJs modules from Google -->
<script src="{% static "js/angular-1.5.0/angular.min.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/angular-1.5.0/angular-resource.min.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/angular-1.5.0/angular-route.min.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/angular-1.5.0/angular-sanitize.min.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/angular-1.5.0/angular-cookies.min.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/angular-1.5.0/angular-mocks.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/angular-1.5.0/angular-scenario.js" %}"></script>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="{% static "js/bootstrap.min.js" %}"></script>
```

I tried using Google CDN for the angular files, but the same problem exists. I tried using angular 1.2.16 instead of 1.5.0, and still get the same damn problem. Any idea why the sample app is not working with my project? Any help is appreciated!

**edit**

If I use angular.js instead of angular.min.js, the problem seems to be on line 3627, which is the start of this loop:

```
for (var i = 0, ii = this.length; i < ii; i++) {
      if (isUndefined(value)) {
        value = fn(this[i], arg1, arg2, arg3);
        if (isDefined(value)) {
          // any function which returns a value needs to be wrapped
          value = jqLite(value);
        }
      } else {
        jqLiteAddNodes(value, fn(this[i], arg1, arg2, arg3));
      }
    }
    return isDefined(value) ? value : this;
  };
```

From the error console, this is whats causing the problem:

> Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

in angular.js:68:12